# 24VDC along side 120VAC Romex?

Tags: electrical, nec, low-voltage

[context: NEC 2023, state of Colorado]

I want to have this 3 gang box turn on overhead lights, pendants, and under cabinet LED lights. There is a [combo dimmer/transformer/driver](https://a.co/d/fVDPIEd) to run LED under cabinet strip lights that transforms the 120vac to 12/24vdc that I'd like to use in one slot in that switch box. This dimmer has a physical barrier built in to isolate the 120v from the 12/24v sections as required by code.

I am unclear on:

1.) Which wire can run I in the walls to the LED strip lights? i.e. 18/2 CL2 or 3 rated for 600v (to match the romex jacket insulation???)

2.) If this wire can run parallel next to the romex up the wall? (I.e. are there distance requirements to maintain from the romex? Required to be run through separate joist/stud holes)

3.) Any other constraints I'm not thinking of?

As you can see this bay already has 120v romex on both sides, so if there are distance requirements like 12", etc, that won't be possible.

[image: wall bay]

Comment: This is SELV wiring,  see the relevant parts of the code that deal with Separated Extra Low Voltage.

Comment: Is your power supply Class 2 or Class 3 rated?

Comment: Separate holes and 2"/50mm separation unless there's a physical barrier. For 24V you don't need CL3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a constraint per se, but more of a "keep your future options open" strategy.

If you'll run the DC wiring using ordinary AC wiring methods (NM/B "Romex" cable, junction boxes, stapling, etc) then you can use those conductors for DC today -- and, if at any point in the future you wish to change out that DC system for something else, perhaps AC-based, the conductors could easily be converted to that use. As an added bonus the heavier gauge wire will have less voltage drop for today's 12/24 V DC system.

One minor catch is that you'll have to take care to bring these conductors into the junction box via entry points on the correct side of the low-high voltage barrier. Another is that the low-voltage components may not be designed to accept 14 or 12 gauge solid wire. In that case, use pigtails of stranded 18 gauge to jumper between the solid building wire and the devices.